# rosserial-python on ROS noetic

Tags: ros, rosserial, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I'm trying to download rosserial on ROS noetic by doing:

**sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-rosserial-python**

However, I always get the same output:

**E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-rosserial-python**

So my question is: How do I download rosserial-python for ROS noetic?
According to the wiki, http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_python , there is already rosserial python for ROS noetic so I don't understand why the command isn't working.
I am using ROS Noetic on a RaspberryPi 3 and I'm following the tutorial: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/raspberry_pi_3_setup/#raspberry-pi-3-setup to try to setup a turtlebot with noetic.

Thank you all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355801/rosserial-python-on-ros-noetic/) by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2020-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the maintainers of `rosserial_python` have not yet released it into ROS Noetic.

- https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/499

In the meantime, you can try building it from source. Clone the repo into your catkin workspace.

```
cd path/to/your/catin/ws/src
git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial.git -b noetic-devel
```

Then build as usual using whatever tool you prefer: `catkin_make` or `catkin_make_isolated` or `catkin build`, ...

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on 2020-06-25**:
thank you :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-26**:
Building from source may not work in this case (or be sufficient). See #q354667 (and a few other Q&As here).